# How to validate a duplicate post request from a form in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having an form which insert a record whenever a post request is made,but the problem is that if someone clicks submit button more than 1 times than duplicate post request are made and at the end same records are getting inserted. I dont want to check that the record is already present or not because the record would be different always. I tried using ValidateAntiForgeryToken filter in controller but it is failing to validate the requests, Below is my View Code.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home",FormMethod.Post,new { onkeydown = "return event.keyCode!=13" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="right-col">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { placeholder = "Name", @class = "small-box" })
 </div>
 <div class="left-col">Email Id :</div>
  <div class="right-col">
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailId, new { placeholder = "Email Id", @class = "small-box",id="resumeemailid" })
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailId)
  </div>
  <div class="left-col">Address :</div>
  <div class="right-col">
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Address, new { placeholder = "Address", @class = "small-box" })
  </div>
  <div class="buttons resume-threebutton">
      <input type="submit" id="register-button" class="gradient-btn" value="@T("Account.Passport.Register.Button.Upload", "Upload")" name="Command" />
       <input type="submit" id="register-button" class="gradient-btn" value="@T("Account.Passport.Button.UploadandAdd", "Upload And Add New")" name="Command" />
       <input type="button" id="register-button" class="gradient-btn" value="@T("Account.Passport.Register.Button.Cancel", "cancel")" name="register-button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("SelectTemplate", "CustomerTemplate")'" />
 </div>
}
```

and below is my controller Post method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(ProductModel model)
{
     //To do add the product here...
}
```

Comment: >I dont want to check that the record is already present or not because the record would be different always. < Then how are they duplicates?

Comment: Maybe you can just to disable a button till current request is sent. What do you think? You can do it by simple JS/jQuery code.

Comment: @laroslav i know i can do it that way at the end, but if the client has disabled Js than he would be able to make duplicate requests.

Comment: Make your button require javascript to submit it.  No matter what you do on the client side, the server side can still receive duplicates.  Tools like PostMan and Fiddler can resend the exact same payload.  The suggestions here can help you prevent the button from being clicked but you still must detect dupes on the server.

Comment: what i am trying to find a solution that some how i can manage to validate the post request through a parameter or whatever in it so that i can determine that this is a duplicate post request.